# Why is "regtest" called "regtest"?

Tags: terminology, regtest

Bitcoin "regtest" is for when you want to run a local version of Bitcoin where the state is only shared within a small community, whereas both "mainnet" and "testnet" are shared with the rest of the world.

I get why its called "mainnet" and "testnet", but where does the word "regtest" come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for "regression test". As you can see here:

> **Regtest**
>
> **Regression test mode**
>
> A local testing environment in which developers can almost instantly
> generate blocks on demand for testing events, and can create private
> satoshis with no real-world value.

https://developer.bitcoin.org/glossary.html?highlight=regression